# Regex to remove all non-digit symbols from string in R

Tags: r, regex, string

How can I extract digits from a string that can have a structure of xxxx.x or xxxx.x-x and combine them as a number? e.g.

```
list <- c("1010.1-1", "1010.2-1", "1010.3-1", "1030-1", "1040-1",
          "1060.1-1", "1060.2-1", "1070-1", "1100.1-1", "1100.2-1")
```

The desired (numeric) output would be:

```
101011, 101021, 101031...
```

I tried

```
regexp <- "([[:digit:]]+)"
solution <- str_extract(list, regexp)
```

However that only extracts the first set of digits; and using something like

```
regexp <- "([[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\-[[:digit:]]+)"
```

returns the first result (data in its initial form) if matched otherwise `NA` for shorter strings. Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove all non-digit symbols:

```
list <- c("1010.1-1", "1010.2-1", "1010.3-1", "1030-1", "1040-1", "1060.1-1", "1060.2-1", "1070-1", "1100.1-1", "1100.2-1")
as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", list))
## => [1] 101011 101021 101031  10301  10401 106011 106021  10701 110011 110021
```

See the [R demo online](http://ideone.com/1IPzIG)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with R but I do know *regular expressions*. When I look at the pattern you're specifying `"([[:digit:]]+)"`. I assume `[[:digit:]]` stands for [0-9], so you're capturing ***one group*** of digits.

It seems to me you're missing a **+** to make it capture multiple groups of digits.

I'd think you'd need to use `"([[:digit:]]+)+"`.